# Setting the title in a settings plist

Tags: ios, title, application-settings

I'm making the settings plist(root.plist) for an app in the settings bundle and, as usual, have some options in a table view. The plist has some child views which come up when we click any of these options. The problem is that the title that comes on the navigation bar depends on the title of the option that was clicked. So, how do I put a custom title for for my child views in the application settings? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, and as you noticed, the NavBar title is the same as title of the selected option. So it's impossible to customize it into the Application Settings.
To have more control, you have to implement settings by yourself into your application.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's impossible, but I'll accept your answer for now :)